# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, axapta

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, created a web-service that add/select data from Microsoft axapta 2009, when trying to add data I get the following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[image: Could not load file or assembly]

I've tried changing the project type to only x86 output and changed IIS server app pool settings to only x86. nothing worked for me

Comment: Just to be sure - you installed the business connector on the machine? :)

Comment: It's installed, I even tried reinstalling it 5 times so far

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for almost a week for a solution. the answer was in removing the reference of the connector from the front-end project and copying the business's connector to bin folder

Answer (score 0):

This particular webapplication required the IIS to run in 64 bit mode and therefore this was changed. The Microsoft.DynamicsBusinessConnectorNet.dll that I was using was the 32bit version – which ofcourse was the cause of the error.

The solution was to enable the application pool to allow 32 bit application at IIS. This is done by:

- Right clicking the application pool and selecting “advanced setting”
- Set the “enable 32-bit applicataions” to true